# Why there is \relax at the end of the definition of \raggedright?

Tags: macros, tex-core

(From the appendix of "The TeXbook")

```
\def\raggedright{\rightskip=0pt plus2em \spaceskip=.3333em \xspaceskip=.5em\relax}
```

It seems that many other plain TeX macros don't end with `\relax`. What makes `\raggedright` so special ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Because otherwise TeX would continue reading the skip unit and this could lead to problems. See exercise 27.4 of the TeXbook for an example.

Comment: Remove `\relax` and try `\raggedright Minuscule bugs can ruin our day`

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik So if I understand it correctly, problem would arise if I say "\raggedright plus 1em", for example.

Comment: @user5938 No, `\raggedright plus 1em` would work because `1em` is a valid measure. It would fail, as egreg commented, if what follows `minus` (or `plus`) is _not_ a lenght, as in `minus`cule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\xspaceskip` is a glue parameter, which enters the scene when it’s nonzero and TeX decides to use the extra space because the current space factor is 2000 or more.

The idea is that in ragged right text no space is flexible. What the interword space, governed by font information or by `\spaceskip` if nonzero, is a matter of taste.

The reason for `\relax` is stopping TeX from looking for a full glue specification, so searching (with expansion) for `plus` or `minus`.

Try, without `\relax`,

```
\raggedright Minuscule bugs can ruin our day.
```

Since keywords are case insensitive, the `Minus` would trigger the search for a dimension.

For the same reason LaTeX’s `\setlength{\foo}{<glue>}` does

```
\foo=<glue>\relax
```